# Is it possible to replace a debian ttyx console window with a graphical application?

Tags: linux, iot

On debian, how can I replace a ttyx console window with a graphical application? I am running debian 9.3(Stretch); it does not come with a graphical desktop as it's more of an Internet of Things version of debian. It comes with 6 ttyx consoles and I want to know whether or not one of these can be replaced with a graphical application. The reason I am trying to figure this out is to view network diagnostics for my server in real-time(I already made the graphical application).

My application uses x windows as a graphical subsystem and my IoT server does have a graphical head.

Comment: Does your IoT server have a graphics head? You haven't told us this, but if it doesn't, you're going to struggle to get graphics on it. [Some detail in your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/452792/edit) about the graphical subsystem your application uses would help. QT? XWindows? Homegrown on a framebuffer? ASCII Art?

Comment: My application uses X Windows as a graphical subsystem. Sorry for not mentioning whether or not my server has a graphical head; it does have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not already done, install `xinit` (`apt-get install xinit`). It will also install all dependencies like `xorg` and graphics drivers.

You need some sort of desktop, you can install a minimalistic one like `openbox` (`apt-get install openbox`).

Afterwards, run `startx` on a tty and you should have a graphical environment.

If you desire an automatic start of the graphical environment, that is possible, too, but currently not part of your question.

Comment: Is openbox open source?

Comment: @shadowstalker75 yes, openbox is open source.